# Use a column value input as a default for another column in the same insert statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know if it is possible to reuse a column input value as a default for another column value input if it is left blank. I've tried to simply stuff the reference after the DEFAULT code.

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(50) DEFAULT name
    );

INSERT INTO members (name) VALUES ('el duderino');
SELECT * FROM members;
```

Desired results;

```
     name     |   username
--------------+--------------
 el duderino  | el duderino
```

The insert statement runs but doesn't find the table as it doesn't get built due to the following error...

> psql:website.sql:38: ERROR:  cannot use column references in default expression

Is it possible to reference the value first name in the default statement in one line? Or does this have to be done in stages?

Comment: What you want is a `TRIGGER`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a `TRIGGER` for this:

Function to be called:

```
create or replace function insert_members_username() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if NEW.username is null then
        NEW.username := NEW.name;
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Calling trigger:

```
create trigger trig_insert_members_username
before insert
on members
for each row
execute procedure insert_members_username();
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/NPNU50638)

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when trying to implement this. I put the create function and create trigger statements after the create table statement, is that the correct format? 
CREATE TRIGGER trig_update_member_username
BEFORE UPDATE ON members
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_members_username();

Comment: @TechSparrow - You can see in the added demo that it works fine. I've changed the names to avoid confusion

Comment: @TechSparrow - It's not `BEFORE UPDATE`. It's `BEFORE INSERT`.

Comment: I did catch that difference in the Demo, but I still made a small typo when I was copying over your example. Everything works as it should now. Thanks a lot! I'm going to read up on these triggers a bit more.

Answer (score 15):

Postgres 12 now features [Generated Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html)!

```sql
CREATE TABLE members (
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (name) STORED
);
```

Comment: Just remember that you cannot edit the value of generated column directly.
UPDATE members SET username = 'el_duderino' WHERE username = 'el duderino'
will not work

Answer (score 13):

If you are getting a similar error when setting default values in Postgres. For example :

> ERROR: cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression LINE 6:
> is_used boolean DEFAULT No,

The solution is to put your default value in single quotes;

Comment: that means default value is 'default'.

Comment: This was my issue thanks, very unclear error message